# Align ImageView to the right with parent layout set to wrap_content

Tags: android

I have a list of items in a horizontal recycler view, and a fairly simple item that should only have a `TextView` set to wrap_content and an `ImageView` that should be aligned to the right of the layout.

Theoretically I should be able to just set a `layout_weight` of 1 on the `TextView`, but that causes a random space to randomly show up sometimes in the view depending on where it is in the recycler view.

Is there anyway to align the close icon to the right, while still keeping the layout/textview width as `wrap_content`? The amount of text can vary quite a bit, so I can't actually set a fixed width. I'm fairly certain that I can't just set a `layout_gravity` of `end` on the `ImageView` since the parent layout's set to wrap_content.

See layout attached.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/min_width"
    android:maxWidth="@dimen/max_width"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <WPTextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try playing with constraint layout.

Comment: You are creating circular references. Size of ImageView depends on LinearLayout and size of LinearLayout depends on ImageView.

Comment: Try setting wrap_content for both height and width in `ImageView`. Or change the wrap_content in `LinearLayout` as @BirendraSingh said is right.

Comment: Woops, the `ImageView` should actually have a fixed width/height, but changing that doesn't affect the alignment of the `ImageView` >_<. I'll take a look at using a `ConstraintLayout` though!

Answer (score 0):

With out knowing what the items are supposed to look like and how it needs to behave it is hard to judge what the problem you are having is.

If the image is just supposed to be a small image to the right of the text you could just add a right drawable to the text view:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableRight

Comment: I tried using a drawableRight as well, but the ImageView actually needs to be aligned with the end of the parent layout, as well as being to the right of the `TextView`. I don't believe there's a way to do that with using a `CompoundDrawable` sadly.

Answer (score 0):

If you can replace the `LinearLayout` by `RelativeLayout` then you are good to with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/min_width"
    android:maxWidth="@dimen/max_width">

    <WPTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Spacing between `TextView` and `ImageView` can be adjusted with margin on them. The properties used in the above code are self-explanatory.

Comment: The `ImageView` needs to be aligned with the end of the parent layout. Is it possible to do that while keeping the wrap_content on the parent? I don't believe you can set `layout_alignParentEnd` with a wrap_content

Comment: RelativeLayout will only be as big as it's Children combined. Since `ImageView` is the last horizontal child so it is already right aligned. There is no need to set `layout_alignParenEnd`.